# How to copy a date within a text cell/row to another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet which has a date mm/dd within text. I would like to locate the date and copy the date only to another row, column, but I don't have any idea about how or where to begin. I've checked this site and on the web, but didn't find a matching situation.

The date is located on the example spreadsheet "Sheet2" column "C". In addition, I would like to know how to possibly increment the dates' month (only) once moved to another Range. The date is a billing date, and the day remains the same each month. Only the month changes, 10/20 - 11/20. See the attached link. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Sample data "JACK IN THE BOX 3521 LYNWOOD CA              09/20"
Sample data "Online Payment 18475739849 To SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA EDISON SCE 09/18"
Sample data "ARCO #42618 10/02 LONG BEACH CA"

[Billing Statement](https://Link%20to%20Spreadsheet)

```
    Sub RemoveDate()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If IsDate(Cells(i, "C")) Then
            'Cells(i, "D") = TimeValue(Cells(i, "C"))
            'Cells(i, "C") = DateValue(Cells(i, "C"))
            Message = "found"
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Minor change last line. Run-time error '9' occurs, Subscript out of range. I noticed that it appears to happen on cells that don't contain dates.

```
     For Each c In Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
        aTxt = Split(Trim(c.Value))
        For i = 1 To UBound(aTxt)
            ' Matching mm/dd
            If aTxt(i) Like "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" Then
                ' Month + 1
                iMonth = Val(Left(aTxt(i), 2)) + 1
                If iMonth = 13 Then iMonth = 1
                aTxt(i) = Format(iMonth, "00") & Mid(aTxt(i), 3)
                Exit For
            End If
            
        Next
        ' Write to next column (B), modify as needed
        'c.Offset(0, 16).Value = Join(aTxt)
         c.Offset(0, 16).Value = aTxt(i)
   Next
End Sub
```

---

This is what I get with `c.Offset(0, 1).Value = VBA.DateSerial(iYr, iMonth, iDay)`

[image]

Comment: Please include sample data in your post. Your URL is broken.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). We also do not accept links to other sites for information required for your question.

Comment: @KenWhite What is the add link control in the editor for? Someone needs to remove it.

Comment: It's for adding a link to additional contextual information, but all necessary information is required to be here in your post, so that it is available to future users. See [ask] and [mre] and [help/on-topic]. When someone is trying to help you, it's generally a bad idea to get snarky or smart-assed. The usual response is *Thank you for letting me know*. You're welcome.

Comment: @KenWhite wasn't trying to be rude. I've been a member for sometime now and this is the first time I've heard that. Thanks for the heads up tho

Comment: @Taller I'm not trying to duplicate the entire line. I only need the date in another row row column. I modified the last line 'c.Offset(0, 16).Value = aTxt(i)' this is where an Run-time error '9' occurs, Subscript out of range. I noticed that it appears to happen on cells that do not contain dates.

Comment: See the updated code.

Comment: @Taller I'm not sure why the output is the entire mm/dd/yyyy format when what I'm looking for is the same date in your column B. mm/dd. So output should read as 10/22

Comment: `Range("D:D").NumberFormatLocal = "mm/dd;@"` will set correct date format on column D.

Comment: @taller That's it works great, thanks a million, I've moved some colums around and made adjustments. I'll try and do the match prime stuff on my own, I should have enough code to set up that task. Thanks again

Comment: @taller I apoligize for the delay, I had a serious surgery scheduled. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It appears that the IsDate function isn't suitable for your case.
- You must split the words and extract the month.
- The code doesn't verify if the string is a valid date.

```vb
Option Explicit
' Output is Text
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range, aTxt, iMonth As Integer
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        aTxt = Split(Trim(c.Value))
        For i = 1 To UBound(aTxt)
            ' Matching mm/dd
            If aTxt(i) Like "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" Then
                ' Month + 1
                iMonth = Val(Left(aTxt(i), 2)) + 1
                If iMonth = 13 Then iMonth = 1
                ' Write to next column
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "'" & Format(iMonth, "00") & Mid(aTxt(i), 3)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit
' Output is Date
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range, aTxt, iMonth As Integer
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim iYr As Integer, iDay As Integer
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B:B").NumberFormatLocal = "mm/dd;@"
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        aTxt = Split(Trim(c.Value))
        For i = 1 To UBound(aTxt)
            ' Matching mm/dd
            If aTxt(i) Like "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" Then
                ' Month + 1
                iYr = VBA.Year(Date)
                iMonth = Val(Left(aTxt(i), 2)) + 1
                iDay = Val(Right(aTxt(i), 2))
                ' Write to next column
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = VBA.DateSerial(iYr, iMonth, iDay)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function (UDF) which does what is required.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function fnParseDate(sToParse As String) As String
' work through text one character at a time looking for the sequence 10/22
Dim sChar1 As String
Dim sChar2 As String
Dim sChar3 As String
Dim sChar4 As String
Dim sChar5 As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Len(sToParse)
 sChar1 = Mid(sToParse, i, 1)
 sChar2 = Mid(sToParse, i + 1, 1)
 sChar3 = Mid(sToParse, i + 2, 1)
 sChar4 = Mid(sToParse, i + 3, 1)
 sChar5 = Mid(sToParse, i + 4, 1)
 If IsNumeric(sChar1) _
    And IsNumeric(sChar2) _
    And (sChar3 = "/") _
    And IsNumeric(sChar4) _
    And IsNumeric(sChar5) _
    Then
        ' date found
        fnParseDate = sChar1 & sChar2 & "/" & sChar4 & sChar5
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

and here is the test data from the OP's original unedited question with the results of using the UDF fnParseDate.

|  | A | B |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JACK IN THE BOX 3521 LYNWOOD CA 09/20 | JACK IN THE BOX 3521 LYNWOOD CA 11/20 | 09/20 | 11/20 |
| 2 | Online Payment 18475739849 To SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA EDISON SCE 09/18 | Online Payment 18475739849 To SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA EDISON SCE 10/18 | 09/18 | 10/18 |
| 3 | ARCO #42618 10/02 LONG BEACH CA | ARCO #42618 11/02 LONG BEACH CA | 10/02 | 11/02 |
| 4 | ARCO #42619 12/03 LONG BEACH CA | ARCO #42619 01/03 LONG BEACH CA | 12/03 | 01/03 |
|  | ARCO #42619 test/03 LONG BEACH CA | ARCO #42619 003 LONG BEACH CA |  |  |

I used the Excel option to read an image Data > From picture > Picture from file and it was only partially successful. There were missing spaces and added spaces in the date. Using the test data above you could extend the code to look for a pattern 7 characters long with a space at each end if the 5 character pattern is not sufficient.

During development I checked and `IsDate` recognises the sequence of characters as a date. I also used `Sheet1.Range("D2").Value = sChar1 & sChar2 & "/" & sChar4 & sChar5` at one point and Excel recognised the date *and* formatted it as a date automatically.